# How to draw a white L shape in the top-left corner using imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a image like below:

[image]

And I wanted to convert into something like below using imagemagick 6. How is that possible? I have gone through chop/shave/crop they all applicable to all sides symmetrically what I need is a partially chopped edges as below:

[image]

I have gone through https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#chop but it helps to chop an entire edge/side but I need to remove edges partially.

Comment: Do you mean you want to draw a white `L` shape in the top-left corner?

Comment: Yes that will also do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that by drawing a simple, white-filled polygon:

```
magick start.png -fill white -draw "polygon 0,0 60,0 60,16 16,16, 16,60 0,60" result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Many Thanks!! @Mark Setchell I'll definitely use this. Let me try the -fill in imagemagick-6 but surely this is what I needed.

Comment: Change `magick` to `convert` and it will work just the same in **ImageMagick** v6.

Comment: yes Did that already this is the answer I was looking for. May be too much to ask! The draw is filling with black color for me instead of white! I am quite sure the code you suggested it is definitely draws what is intended. I need to fix at my end. Although I am running the commands in java after building them. But it eventually turns into below: convert -density 300 ai:- -trim -gravity Center +repage -adaptive-resize %894x%894! -fill white -draw "polygon 0,0 60,0 60,16 16,16, 16,60 0,60"

Comment: Try adding `-background magenta` near the start of the command to see if it is transparency and the background causing you trouble. If it is, change it to `-background white`.